# Go float64 does not work for latitude and longitude

Tags: go, numbers, precision

I'm trying to parse latitude and longitude from a json object with precision, and I picked float64 for the job. However float64 is somehow rounding the number and I'm not sure what to do in order to avoid rounding.

I've created a quick snippet so you can execute the problem:
http://play.golang.org/p/9g6Imn-7GK

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Position struct {
    Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
    Lon float64 `json:"lon"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"lat":13.519004709972312,"lon": -13.519004709972312}`
    pos := Position{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pos)

    if !reflect.DeepEqual(s, &pos) {
        fmt.Printf("\nExpected %#v\nbut got  %#v", s, pos)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `math/big` if you want higher precision than float64.

Comment: I've edited with the full code. Thanks

Comment: @JimB, not sure how to do this, can you maybe modify the playground example with your suggestion ?

Comment: As mentioned, you can (should?) just use float64 and live with rounding. If you have a reason to wish to keep the exact string perhaps [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) may be of some use.

Comment: Also the question you have to ask yourself is how is the input generated anyway? If double-precision number has been used at source, the very last digits cannot be trusted anyway. You can reliably represent up to 15 decimal digits by using `float64`, but your input has 17.

Comment: BTW, an example using `json.Numer` (useful if a desired use case is re-marshalling the exact representation unchanged when not doing calculations) might be something like this (also shows using big.Rat; very much overkill for lat+long IMO): https://play.golang.org/p/TqhvyS8aRs

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### A practical solution:

Do nothing.

The difference in the numbers is about a tenth of the width of a single small atom, and your measurements can't possibly be that precise.

The eighth decimal place (you have 15 in your numbers) represents a distance of about 1.1mm. I doubt if your measurements are accurate to this degree, and anything more is getting really silly. The 5th decimal place is about 1.1m, which is in the realm of sanity, and not affected by floating point errors.

The [wikipedia page on Decimal Degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) may be helpful in determining which values are reasonable for your project.

### Some considerations:

There are two potential issues at play:

1. **Floating point**:

   Some reading that might shed light on floating point issues:

   - [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic or Why don’t my numbers add up?](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
   - [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

   If you read these, and understand how floating point works in
   practice, you *may* be enlightened, and understand what's happening
   and how to work around it.
2. **Precision of measurement**:

   This, in my opinion, is the bigger issue. One number you posted was `13.519004709972312`, which was displayed as `13.519004709972313`. Whether the value has "changed" or not (see: 1), every software calculator I tried to calculate the difference between these values returned `0`, which is indicative.

   Doing the calculation by hand revealed a difference of `0.000000000000001` in the values. That is, a 14 zeroes before the trailing one, or `1^-15`.

   The [wikipedia page on Latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) says:

   > the meridian length of 1 degree of latitude on the sphere is **111.2 km**.

   Working backward from this, *the difference in locations represented by the 15th decimal place in a latitude corresponds to a distance of approximately 0.00000011mm*, or 0.11nanometers.

   From the The Physics Factbook's [Diameter of an Atom](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/MichaelPhillip.shtml) page:

   > An atom is a million times smaller than the thickest human hair. The diameter of an atom ranges from about 0.1 to 0.5 nanometers

   Therefore, your measurement would be "off" by at most 1/10 of the diameter of a single atom.

   Even if all my calculations were off by a million or billion times, the distances would still be so small that they would not matter in practice!

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ThomasModeneis Maybe you wanna accept the guy's answer? :)